# how make link on desktop or in dock with a service just press a right button all that in an applescript executed in automator

Tags: service, applescript, automator, right-click

The following script is to be placed in a creation of service in automator.

Thus open Automator and select new service. For files and folder link they are placed on the desktop just application can be placed in the Dock ( you have the script below you can modifie all that you want.

On the left part of automator select utility, double click on Execute an script of  applescript. In a right part you see window open, on the item " service receive a select " you choose " Files and Folders ".

Now below in window "Execute an Applescript " inside

" on run {input,parameters}"

you can put the script below.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set input to POSIX path of input

    set fich to POSIX path of input

    set ft to {}

    set fold to {}

    set sn to {}

    set Nm to {}



    set {file type:ft} to info for POSIX path of fich

    if ft is not "APPL" then

        set input to input

        set vhdoudmg to input as Unicode text

        set input to POSIX path of vhdoudmg

        set sn to ""

        try

            set {name:Nm} to info for file vhdoudmg

        end try

        if sn is "" then

            set lelien to "/Users/username/Desktop/

" & Nm

        else

            set lelien to "/Users/username/Desktop/

" & sn

        end if

        set vhdoudmg to do shell script "ln -s -v " & quoted form of input & " " & quoted form of lelien

    else

        set Reponse to display dialog " Choose to create the symbolic link on the Desktop or Application in the Dock " & return buttons {" The link on the Desktop ", " Application in the Dock "}

        set Choix to button returned of Reponse



        if " Application in the Dock " is in Choix then

            try

                set theFile to POSIX path of input

            end try

            try

                tell application "Dock" to quit

            end try

            do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</k ey><string>" & theFile & "</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>' "

            try

                tell application "Dock" to activate

            end try



        else

            set input to POSIX path of input



            set vhdoudmg to input as Unicode text

            set input to POSIX path of vhdoudmg

            set fich to do shell script "echo " & input

            try

                set {name:Nm} to info for file vhdoudmg

            end try

            set lelien to "/Users/username/Desktop/" & Nm

            set vhdoudmg to do shell script "ln -s -v " & quoted form of input & " " & quoted form of lelien



        end if

    end if

    return input

end run
```

And now you can place this workflow in /Users/yourname/Library/Services and when you click rigth on your mouse button, il you go on context menu on Services in a choice you can see the name of this script ( the name  which you would have given it during the creation.)

Thus open Automator and select new service. For files and folder link they are placed on the desktop just application can be placed in the Dock ( you have the script below you can modifie all that you want.

Comment: You should replace `/Users/username/Desktop/` with `POSIX path of (path to desktop)` to make the script portable.

Comment: the script its here you can make that you want  with all

Comment: I know but if somebody tries the script who is not familiar with AppleScript the script will not work as announced.

Comment: and why the script not work as announced ?

Comment: Because `username` in `/Users/username/Desktop/` is different on every computer.

Comment: I say username so that everyone understands that this is their username and that they have to change it so that it corresponds to them obviously. When one observes code, scripts, one must suspect that they do not apply to a person but to all people. It must come from the one who observes not from the one who does. It's ok?

Comment: @vadian has a valid point and offered an improvement. At the very least, explicitly state the need to change hard-coded literals in your code. It looks like you're offering a solution to a problem, but that's not obvious. It's great that you want to share solutions, but please do so by posting a _problem statement_ as a _question_, and then posting the _solution_ as an _answer_ - see the [relevant help-center article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: with my very great intelligence (compared to others) I write: you can modify anything you want. This is what is posted before you belongs to you, you do what you want.
You must, of course, adjust the names or path at your convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Good evening just for a shorter and just as effective script.***

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set input to POSIX path of input
    set fich to POSIX path of input
    set ft to {}
    set Nm to {}

        set {name:Nm,file type:ft} to info for POSIX path of fich

            set input to input
            set vhdoudmg to input as Unicode text
            set input to POSIX path of vhdoudmg
                    set lelien to "/Users/username/Desktop/" & Nm


                if ft is not "APPL" then
            set vhdoudmg to do shell script "ln -s -v " & quoted form of input & " " & quoted form of lelien
        else
set Reponse to display dialog " Choose to create the symbolic link on the Desktop or Application in the Dock " & return buttons {" The link on the Desktop ", " Application in the Dock "}

    set Choix to button returned of Reponse
   if " Application in the Dock " is in Choix then
                try
                    set theFile to POSIX path of input
                end try
                try
                    tell application "Dock" to quit
                end try
                do shell script "defaults write com.apple.dock persistent-apps -array-add '<dict><key>tile-data</key><dict><key>file-data</key><dict><key>_CFURLString</key><string>" & theFile & "</string><key>_CFURLStringType</key><integer>0</integer></dict></dict></dict>'"
                try
                    tell application "Dock" to activate
                end try

            else

                set vhdoudmg to do shell script "ln -s -v " & quoted form of input & " " & quoted form of lelien

            end if
        end if
    return input
end run
```